# Is Homunculus working when using The Tall Man's Finger?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

I recently found the item [Homunculus](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/homunculus) while using [The Tall Man's Finger](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/the-tall-mans-finger) on my 70 pet doc.

Is there any way to tell if those stack? I do not see any Zombie Dogs summoned to my side, but they could be added to my Gargantuan Dog.

Comment: Have went into combat to test this?  Most items in D3 do not stack, although the concept is horrible in any manner of thinking.

Comment: That is my question. I cannot properly test it because all my dogs are only one.

Comment: Did you notice how much damage the Gardantuan Dog does? Is it a multiple of single dog damage? Anyway, you could note damage numbers of a normal and potentially boosted Gargantuan dog.

Comment: Oh wait. Homunculus doesn't summon any _extra_ dogs over your maximum count (3, or up to 5 with passives), so it should not have any effect, as 1 gargantuan dog is already the maximum. The question is - do **Midnight Feast** and **Zombie Handler** boost the dog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I can't comment, I'll just add an answer here. The mask summons a dog until you have cap dogs. IF your cap is 5 with talents it will summon 'till you reach that point. All it does is that it makes you not having to resummon constantly if they die. Im assuming it's got to do with having the dogs explode and automatically resummon, which none does.

Using TMF + Talents does matter. TMF makes the dogs about 1.5x more effective so it combines all the dogs and then 1.5 its dmg output from my experience.

Without any talents TMF takes the 3x dogs and combines it then upps the dmg vs with all the talents its 5x dogs + buff.

So to answer your original question theres absolutely no synergy between the 2 items to my knowledge.

Comment: If your Gargantuan Dog dies, won't the Homunculus summon a new one within four to six seconds?

Comment: i would have to test this and see if it works, but the problem i see with this is, that if you "tank dog" dies youll get 1 shotted. Its though as nails. In what kinda situation might this occur? i cant think of any